# How to show dates in xAxis using Highcharts.js

Tags: highcharts

I'm feeding my Highcharts.js `series` object with data containing date and a number, for example: `["2017-1-22",262]` which shows up correctly when hovering a point, but which is not displayed correctly in the xAxis. Below codes does not do much, probably because the date format is not what Highcharts expects? But what format is expected? Unixtime does not seem to work.

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/80v2k0tv/

Comment: Highcharts needs dates to be time in milliseconds Date.UTC() in javascript is an easy way to get this.

Comment: @ewolden If I feed it with 1485648000, which resembles January 29, 2017 12:00:00 AM, it still does not work.

Comment: Thats because that is in seconds, not milliseconds. You need to use unixtime * 1000

Answer (score 2):

Highcharts expects time in the form of milliseconds since 1970.

See for example: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.x

> The x value of the point. For datetime axes, the X value is the timestamp in milliseconds since 1970.

Unixtime is in seconds, so using unixtime * 1000 will give the correct highcharts time.